# How long does it take to accelerate to 10$ms^{-1}$ using a 10W laser?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy, acceleration, laser

Given a laser of $P=10W$ and a space vessel of $100kg$, how long would it take to accelerate to a velocity of $10 m/s$ using the laser as propulsion?

My train of thought is that by using $E=Pt$ and $E_k=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ the time can be found. By setting these two equal I find a time of $500s$. This seems ridiculous since things like solar sails work very slowly. What am I missing here?

Comment: To calculate the speed of the space vessel, you need to use conservation of momentum instead of energy. That 10J of energy is radiated to one side does not mean that the ship picks up 10J in kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The momentum of the ship  would be $m\cdot v=\frac{P\cdot t}{c}, c=3*10^8m/s$